# FEM Python book

Tags: finite-element, pde, python, reference-request

Is there any book or site available with Finite element Method for partial differential equations with python code apart from Fenics?

Comment: I know this one: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030239565 (Compatible Finite Element Methods for Geophysical Flows), which uses firedrake: https://www.firedrakeproject.org. However, firedrake is very similar to FEniCS and thus, may be not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [Introduction to Numerical Methods for Variational Problems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030237875) by Langtangen and Mardal.

Besides that, you could check:

- [scikit-fem](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-fem/#description).
- [SfePy](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/index.html).

I would also suggest our own course

- [Introductory Finite Elements](https://github.com/AppliedMechanics-EAFIT/Introductory-Finite-Elements). It has Notebooks with the material and lecture notes;

and our own package [SolidsPy](https://solidspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).